# setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) never called

Tags: spring

I'm trying to get the Spring application context and then call its method getBean("beanName") to get a specific bean but I'm having a null pointer exception indicating that the context is null. When I put a breakpoint inside the setApplicationContext() method, I found out that this method is never called which is weird since this method should be called after spring finishes beans instantiation. I looked for some similar questions here but none worked for me.

this is my code:

```
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanName){
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Set the `ApplicationContext` that this object runs in.
>
> Normally this call will be used to initialize the object.
>
> The `ApplicationContext` object to be used by this object.

Add `@Component`.

```
@Component
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        return CONTEXT;
    }
}
```

Use `ApplicationContext`.

```
TheBeanInstance bean = SpringApplicationContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(requiredType);
```

[ApplicationContextAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)