# ApplicationContext.setApplicationContext is not called, not lazy loading problem

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I need to get a reference to Spring bean in POJO. It seems to me a cleaner way to look it up with `ApplicationContext` rather than passing it in a constructor or setter, as it is internal functionality which caller does not need to know. Unfortunately the `setApplicationContext()` method is never called and `getBean()` results in NPE at runtime (long after Spring is initialized). I tried to turn off lazy initialization without luck. Spring boot 2.4.0. Any idea?

Some referencesI looked up already:

- [applicationContextProvider is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133291/applicationcontextprovider-is-not-being-called)
- [setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506177/setapplicationcontextapplicationcontext-applicationcontext-never-called)

Source code:

```
@Component("SpringContext")
@Lazy(false)
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return ctx.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.ctx = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you "need to get a reference to Spring bean in POJO", then you can hardly call it "POJO"!? Call it "bean" (turn your perspective), and all problems are gone..

Comment: I have not found a bravery to convert POJO to request scope bean yet. This code is legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the `SpringContext` class in a package with smaller lexicographical order, for example, `com.aaaa.SpringContext`, worked for me. Weird, but solved the problem.

It looks like SpringBoot scans packages in a similar order and we need to make sure `SpringContext` is scanned before being used.